# Product.find({category: req.params.category}) doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Now in product schema, I have a category attached to it like that

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e6dfde62764a11b34ccc9a3"),
        "title" : "t-shirt",
        "price" : 12,
        "category" : "T-shirts",
        "description" : "<p>tshirts description goes here</p>\r\n",
        "images" : [ ],
        "__v" : 0
```

and my route is like that:

```
router.get('/category/:category', function(req, res){
    var categorySlug = req.params.category;
    Category.findOne({slug: categorySlug}, function(err, category){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            Product.find({category: categorySlug}, function(err, products){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(category)
                    console.log(products)
                    res.render('client/cat_product', {products, category, title: products.title});
                }
            })
        }

    })
})
```

The problem is: 
when I console.log(category) it displays the category normally but when I console.log(products) it gives me a blank array with no products in it

these are the schema models for the category and the product:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug: String,
    products: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        }
    ]

});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
module.exports = Category;
```

---

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    images: [
        {
            url: String,
            public_id: String
        }
    ]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: Hey there, I think I know where is the problem. First, can you let me know what you are trying to achieve? it is not clear to me.

Comment: I have three categories for products one for t-shirts and one for movies and one for car and i want to get all products that have its category, all products appear in the home page but don't appear by category and when i try to find it by category it gives me an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution may work, if not, please, let me know what you see as output. I was able to test the solution on a simple problem I have created, but I have no idea regarding the details of yours, your question does not leave it clear, and you did not provide further details.

```
router.get("/category/:category", function(req, res) {
  var categorySlug = req.params.category;
  res.send(
    res.render("client/cat_product", {
      products: await Product.find({ category: categorySlug }) ,
      category: await Category.findOne({ slug: categorySlug }) ,
      title: await await Product.find({ category: categorySlug }).select("title")
    })
  );
});
```

If you have several products, coming from `Category.findOne`, you may need to do something like `Category.findOne().populate("products")`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it gave me this error 

 products: await Product.find({ category: categorySlug }) ,
                      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: okay that error appeared cuz u are using await without putting async before the function, i put it and there is no any error but still doesn't show the product by category

Comment: Hey there, can you try something like `console.log (await Product.find({ category: categorySlug }))` after `var categorySlug = req.params.category`, and let me know what comes out. I want to see what comes out. It supposes to give the product, if not, there is something wrong, or something I was unable to grasp.

Comment: Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    opts: {
      bufferCommands: true,
      capped: false,
      autoCreate: undefined,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined

Comment: },
    name: 'products',
    collectionName: 'products',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 1,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: true,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,

Comment: _listening: false,
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      name: 'cms-cart1',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      user: undefined,
      pass: undefined,
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      db: [Db]
    },

Comment: queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined
    }
  },

Comment: model: Model { Product },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: {
      title: [Object],
      description: [Object],
      category: [Object],
      price: [Object],
      images: [Array]
    },
    paths: {
      title: [SchemaString],
      description: [SchemaString],
      category: [SchemaString],
      price: [SchemaNumber],
      images: [DocumentArrayPath],
      _id: [ObjectId],
      __v: [SchemaNumber]

Comment: there is more it's very big

Comment: it seems that it is giving back the query, instead of the document. it happens when somehow await is not working. I need to think about it! You said you add async, so it should work.

Comment: okay i this time didn't add async await but after i put it it gave me an empty array sorry for this miss understanding

Comment: Are you sure you have data in the dataset?

Comment: try this `Product.find({ category: categorySlug }, (err, result)=>{ console.log(result)})`, and let me know

Comment: this is one of the products in the data base from mongoshell for example:
 db.products.find().pretty()

        "_id" : ObjectId("5e6ba62252531009c489ef32"),
        "title" : "Lambo",
        "price" : 450000,
        "category" : "Cars",
        "description" : "<h1>Lamborghini</h1>\r\n\r\n<p>The sexiest car.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n",
        "images" : [ ],
        "__v" : 0
}

and tried this last comment and gives me empty array

Comment: try this `Product.find({ category: "cars"}, (err, result)=>{ console.log(result)})`, and let me know what comes out. it should give the example you gave, and any other that belongs to the same category.

Comment: Okay I now know why it wasn't getting the products by category it because : category" : "Cars"

Comment: Cars is capitalized

Comment: I now updated the route of creating the categories and made the slug.toLowerCase and updated the whole database and made a new one and it worked 
thank u so much for helping me couldn't realize that without you helping thank u so much and so sorry for disturbing you.